# IIFE inside $(document).ready or the other way around

Tags: javascript, jquery

My colleague has been extensively using IIFE inside (document).ready in his code. Now, I've read this post:

[JQuery best practise, using $(document).ready inside an IIFE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930807/jquery-best-practise-using-document-ready-inside-an-iife)

This got me thinking if we should use $(document).ready inside IIFE or is it also fine the other way around as my colleague is doing.

So basically, his code is setup like this:

```
jQuery(function() {
    (function($) {
        //...
        // Code here
        //...
    })(jQuery);
});
```

Is what he is doing generally fine?

Comment: If all he's trying to do is scope a local `$` to insulate from  `window.$` which can conflict with other libraries can do that in  the outer function by adding `$` argument or as you suggest wrap the ready function in the IIFE

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Some may argue that this is a matter of style/opinion, but if you consider the typical goal of an IIFE in that context I believe the answer is **yes, it is acceptable to use your alternative way, but there is a potential drawback**.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) has to say that:

> Immediately-invoked function expressions can be used to avoid variable hoisting from within blocks, protect against polluting the global environment and simultaneously allow public access to methods while retaining privacy for variables defined within the function.

Neither method pollutes the global namespace, because they don't declare any variables. Therefore, it should be fine to use either way. Although note that it is *partially* redundant because the function handler for the `ready` event already creates a new scope, and also note it is the most common practice to see IIFE functions encapsulate **all** of the code in a file.

---

One drawback to the way that your colleague is using: If you did want to do some javascript logic that didn't depend on the DOM being ready, then you would *not* have the benefits of the IIFE if you put your code outside of the IIFE. So something such as this would not be safe:

```
// Non-DOM-ready-required code here (NOT scope-safe)
jQuery(function() {
    (function($) {
        //...
        // DOM-ready-required code here
        //...
    })(jQuery);
});
```

Using the common style gives you the full IIFE benefit:

```
(function($) {
    // Non-DOM-ready-required code here (scope-safe)
    $(function() {
      //...
      // DOM-ready-required code here
      //...
    });
 })(jQuery);
```

Comment: The drawback is one example for the general problem that the 'style' doesn't make much sense. Any benefits of an IIFE are not relevant because the code is already running in a function, one that runs when the document is ready. So when the document is ready, not one, but two functions run, with the first already offering all the advantages of an IIFE. It works, but it offers no benefits.

Comment: @nomve You're correct. The reason I only said "partially redundant" is because the asker's colleague may be doing it for some other reason (reset the value of `this`, get a safe-scoped version of `$`, etc..)

Comment: I understood from the question and your answer that it's always done like this. As a special case fine, but in general I agree with what you've already said - there are more typical cases where it causes more issues.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. This answer really helped me a lot after some painful days.

Comment: @AdolfoF.IbarraLandeo Thanks for letting me know, I'm glad it was useful!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, your colleague is jumping through an extra hoop for no reason. I'm going to ignore the outer `$(document).ready` as it's of no real consequence.

```
/*jQuery(*/function() {
    (function($) {
        //...
        // Code here
        //...
    })(jQuery);
}/*);*/
```

Using an IIFE as the entire body of the callback to jQuery confers no extra benefit in scope isolation. It's the same as if the code were

```
/*jQuery(*/function() {

        //...
        // Code here
        //...

});
```

The only thing that the IIFE has done is allow you to reference `jQuery` as `$`.

Now, if there were more substantive code inside the callback, then there could be some benefit in using an inner IIFE. In the following example, the callback contains two IIFEs,

```
jQuery(function() {
    // IIFE
    (function($) {
        //...
        // Code here
        //...
    })(jQuery);
    // IIFE 2
    (function($) {
        //...
        // Code here
        //...
    })(jQuery);
});
```

and the use of IIFE's allows scope isolation between the two blocks of code.

Back to the main question:

> This got me thinking if we should use `$(document).ready` inside IIFE or
>   is it also fine the other way around as my colleague is doing.

Now, to be honest, I don't understand why either of these should be regarded as a best practice, even after looking at your [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930807/jquery-best-practise-using-document-ready-inside-an-iife). The people who answered never explained ***why*** it should be a best practice.

Looking at

```
(function($) {     
 $(document).ready(function() {   
    // other code here  
  });    
})(jQuery);
```

versus

```
//(function($) {     
 $(document).ready(function() {   
    // other code here  
  });    
//})(jQuery);
```

There really isn't any significant advantage. Just as in my earlier example, the use of the IIFE offers no scope isolation advantage, and does nothing other than to allow you to reference `jQuery` via `$`.

However, in the actual linked question , the code looks like this:

```
(function($) {    
   // other code here 1
 $(document).ready(function() {   
    // other code here 2 
  });    
})(jQuery);
```

and in this case, the IIFE **does** serve a purpose of keeping the variables used in `other code here 1` from leaking out to global scope. But this has nothing at all to do with `$(document).ready()`. Restructuring the code as

```
(function($) {    
   // other code here 1   
})(jQuery);

jQuery(document).ready(function() {   
   // other code here 2 
});
```

does the same thing.

The moral of this answer is that using an IIFE to wrap loose code that's not already inside a function gives you benefits, while wrapping code that's already inside a function doesn't give you anything (unless you count changing the reference).