# Is wrapping a js code into .ready() twice reasonable?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I seen a code snippet somewhere look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function($){ $.fn.disableSelection = function() {
        return this.attr('unselectable', 'on')
                   .css('user-select', 'none')
                   .on('selectstart', false); }; })(jQuery);

})
```

As you know, this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

and this

```
(function($){
```

are identical. So why should a programmer does so? Isn't `(function($){` redundant in code above?

Comment: `$(function() { ... })` is not the same as `(function($) { ... })(jQuery)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930807/jquery-best-practice-using-document-ready-inside-an-iife, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2662778/what-is-the-difference-between-these-jquery-ready-functions

Comment: The inner one is just a plain IIFE, not a ready wrapper.

Comment: @Bergi thank you .. my answer is exactly the link you provided.

Comment: Downvoter please leave a comment and explain what's wrong with my question?

Comment: @Bergi One question else: I have a function like this `function test(){ /*do stuff*/ );}`. Now I can call it like either `test();` or `$(test());`. They seem identical too me. Both approaches call that function. Is there any different between them?

Comment: `$(test())` will call jQuery with the return value of `test()` - most likely `undefined`, which is why it doesn't do anything. You probably meant `$(test)`, where jQuery installs the function as a dom ready handler - quite different from `test()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> As you know, this
>
> $(document).ready(function(){
>
> and this
>
> (function($){

No, they are not identical. They have different purpose.

The first gets handler when the html document is ready.

`(function(){...})();` will be executed as soon as it is encountered in the script.

The second is self executing function. That doesn't wait for document ready.

> Isn't (function($){ redundant in code above?

And I agree that the `(function($){` is redundant. There is no need of that.

Comment: Aren't they? really? But I remember I've read somewhere `.ready()` is outdated and we have to use something like `(function($){` instead of that. Do you know what been that thing?

Comment: @stack they aren't say. You misunderstood it wrong or the article is wrong.

Comment: @ANS the documentation says they are equivalent.

Comment: @julekgwa Which documentation says that what is equivalent? The two lines the question asks about are definitely not identical.

Comment: @Bergi this answer has been edited I was pointing out the `$(document).ready(function(){` and `(function($){` are equivalent.

Comment: @julekgwa Ok we have a confusion here. There are two things.  If you look at the code you wrote here in your comment (`$(document).ready(function(){`). `ready` function used the `self invoked` function inside of it. That doesn't mean `ready` and `self invoked` are equal

Comment: @julekgwa Thanks. But no, [they are not equivalent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3259496/jquery-document-ready-vs-self-calling-anonymous-function).

Comment: @Bergi i was talking about `$(document).ready(function(){` and `$(function() {` from the documentation it says they are equivalent.