# How to Load an external jQuery File

Tags: jquery, html-table

I am trying to learn how to create my own external jQuery file to create a table. I found some code which looks good and have found out how to create the external file. I have added it to the head of the html page under the line that adds jQuery. Like this:

```
<script src="../js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/my_table.js"></script>
```

I get no errors in the console.

I believe I can add some code to the head to call it on (document).ready and then add a div to the page. All my efforts do not work. I am unsure what to call the div and what to put in (document).ready and have tried all variations I can think of by looking at the jQuery code. Also is it possible to put the (document).ready in the external file itself in some way (other external files I have used do not require me to add (document).ready to the head)?

This is the code from the external jQuery file:

```
function createTable() {
// create table
var $table = $('<table>');
// caption
$table.append('<caption>MyTable</caption>')
// thead
.append('<thead>').children('thead')
.append('<tr />').children('tr').append('<th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th><th>D</th>');

//tbody
var $tbody = $table.append('<tbody />').children('tbody');

// add row
$tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
.append("<td>val</td>")
.append("<td>val</td>")
.append("<td>val</td>")
.append("<td>val</td>");

// add another row
$tbody.append('<tr />').children('tr:last')
.append("<td>val</td>")
.append("<td>val</td>")
.append("<td>val</td>")
.append("<td>val</td>");

// add table to dom
$table.appendTo('#dynamicTable');
}

( jQuery );
```

This is the css:

```
.dynamicTable { font:.7em Arial; border:1px solid gray; }
    .dynamicTableTh { background-color:#584df0; color:White;}
    .dynamicTableTd { padding:3px; width:90px; color:red }
```

Comment: The function looks good but you are not calling it anywhere so far. Take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930807) on how to autoexecute your script.

Comment: Thanks, that has sorted it. But css not working.

Comment: Two issues: 1- The div seems to have an id, but the css targets a class. 2- The `td`s and `th`s don't have any class so you need to target the tags: `#dynamicTable th` and `#dynamicTable td`

Comment: Thanks very much. Sorted again. Very grateful.

Comment: I think I need to add a class to a th in each row so I can have a title for each row a different size to the column th? I want the first column to be a different width to the rest of the columns (I hope this makes sense). I will open a new question after I have had another go at doing it myself.