# Increment/decrement count of checked checkboxes

Tags: jquery, toggle

I want the toggles to be counted and they are not. When I press one of them the counter is increased to `1` and stuck. When I decrease the counter it's `-1`.

The expected result is when a toggle is on the counter is increased (`counter++`) and when it is off the counter should be decreased (`counter--`).

The toggles are created in Bootstrap.

```js
(function() {
  $(() => {
    let counter = 0
    for (let index = 1; index < 10; index++) {
      let div = $("<div>").addClass("custom-control custom-switch");
      let myLabel = createLabel("toggle" + index);
      let myCheckbox = createCheckbox("toggle" + index, counter);

      $(div).append(myCheckbox, myLabel);
      $("#container").append(div);
    }
  });
})();

function createLabel(id) {
  return $(`<label for=${id} class=custom-control-label>${id}&nbsp;</label>`);
}

function createCheckbox(id, counter) {
  return $(`<input type=checkbox class=custom-control-input id=${id}>`).click(() => {
    onCheckBoxSwitchToggled(id, counter);
  });
}

function onCheckBoxSwitchToggled(id, counter) {
  $(`input[id=${id}`).on("change", function() {
    if (counter < 6) {
      if ($(this).prop("checked") === true) {
        counter++
        $("#text").text(counter)
      } else {
        counter--
        $("#text").text(counter)
      }
    } else {
      alert("over than 5")
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<p id="text"></p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
<div class="container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">The chosen coins</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

There's quite a few issues in your code.

- You're using an IIFE instead of a document.ready handler
- You're placing a function inside a jQuery object. Don't do that. You don't need it in this case anyway, just put the logic within the document.ready handler to be executed when the DOM loads.
- You're selecting an `id` using an attribute selector instead of an actual id selector. That attribute selector is also missing the closing `]`
- `div` already holds a jQuery object, you don't need to put it in another one.
- The checkbox inputs you create are missing the `name` and `value` attributes.
- Use the `change` event on checkbox  and radio inputs, not `click`. This is for accessibility reasons.
- Use a single delegated event handler on dynamic content instead of attaching a new event handler clone every time the element is created
- Remove the nested event handler in `onCheckBoxSwitchToggled`. You don't need it as that event already runs when the checkbox is interacted with anyway.

However the main issue with your logic is that you're relying on the `counter` argument which is defined globally. Instead just use the `length` property along with the `:checked` selector to get the number of checked boxes.

Below is a working example. Note that the `createLabel()` and `createCheckbox()` methods are now almost entirely redundant and can be removed. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  for (let index = 1; index < 10; index++) {
    let $div = $("<div>").addClass("custom-control custom-switch");
    let $label = createLabel("toggle" + index);
    let $checkbox = createCheckbox("toggle" + index);
    $div.append($checkbox, $label);
    $("#container").append($div);
  }
  
  $('#container').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
    let counter = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
    $('#text').text(counter);
  
    if (counter > 5)
      console.log("over  5")
    });
});

function createLabel(id) {
  return $(`<label for="${id}" class="custom-control-label">${id}&nbsp;</label>`);
}

function createCheckbox(id) {
  return $(`<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="${id}" name="foo" value="${id}">`)
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
<p id="text"></p>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open modal</button>
<div class="container" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h4 class="modal-title">The chosen coins</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No, not at all. IIFEs execute immediately, document.ready executes when, as the name implies, the document is ready. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930807/jquery-best-practice-using-document-ready-inside-an-iife/24930981

Comment: "You're placing a function inside a jQuery object. Don't do that. You don't need it in this case anyway, just put the logic within the document.ready handler to be executed when the DOM loads."   it's not a Jquery object ($(() =>)  is a function?

Comment: "The checkbox inputs you create are missing the name and value attributes."
it's not critical

Comment: `it's not a Jquery object ($(() =>) is a function?` No, `$()` is a jquery object. `$(() => {})` is an arrow function inside a jQuery object.

Comment: $(object) and what wraps the object is a function?

Comment: $('#container').on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
    let counter = $(':checkbox:checked').length;
 and the colon what it means?

Comment: They are jQuery selectors: https://api.jquery.com/checkbox-selector/ & https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

Comment: but the purpose of them is when the web page's loaded some code's executed

Comment: so when i use document ready in the code? i understood that in document ready the code's executed after the dom's loaded and iife is immediatly. when i need the document ready?

Comment: the usage of document ready is before ab event?$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){  -like this?