# The connection does not start with web page

Tags: javascript, sockets, connection, plc, modbus-tcp

```js
!function(){!function(){Function.prototype.method=function(name,func){return this.prototype[name]=func,this},Function.method("inherits",function(superCtor){return this.super_=superCtor,this.prototype=Object.create(superCtor.prototype,{constructor:{value:this,enumerable:!1,writable:!0,configurable:!0}}),this});var Events=function(){if(!(this instanceof Events))return new Events;var cbList={};this.fire=function(name,args){if(cbList[name]){for(var i in cbList[name])cbList[name][i].apply(this,args);return this}},this.fireLater=function(name,args){return void 0===args&&(args=[]),function(){var aA=Array.protoype.slice.call(arguments,0),a=args.concat(aA);this.fire(name,a.length>0?a:void 0)}.bind(this)},this.on=function(name,func){return cbList.hasOwnProperty(name)||(cbList[name]=[]),cbList[name].push(func),{name:name,index:cbList[name].length-1}},this.off=function(id){return cbList[id.name].splice(id.index),this}},StateMachine=function(initState){if(!(this instanceof StateMachine))return new StateMachine(initState);Events.call(this);var state=initState;this.inState=function(newState){return state===newState},this.getState=function(){return state},this.setState=function(newState){var oldState=state;return state=newState,this.fire("state_changed",[oldState,newState]),this}};StateMachine.inherits(Events);var MBAP_TID=0,MBAP_PID=2,MBAP_LEN=4,MBAP_UID=6,BODY_FC=0,BODY_START=1,BODY_COUNT=3,READ_COILS=1,READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS=3,READ_INPUT_REGISTERS=4,WRITE_SINGLE_COIL=5,WRITE_SINGLE_REGISTER=6,WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS=16,ModbusRequest=function(id,length){if(!(this instanceof ModbusRequest))return new ModbusRequest(id,length);var deferred=$.Deferred(),packet=new ArrayBuffer(length),header=new DataView(packet,0,7),timeout=null,init=function(){header.setUint16(MBAP_TID,id),header.setUint16(MBAP_PID,0),header.setUint16(MBAP_LEN,length-6),header.setUint8(MBAP_UID,255)}.bind(this);this.getId=function(){return id},this.getPacket=function(){return packet},this.getPromise=function(){return deferred.promise()},this.reject=function(){return deferred.reject.apply(null,arguments),this},this.resolve=function(){return deferred.resolve.apply(null,arguments),this},this.getTimeout=function(){return timeout},this.setTimeout=function(to){return timeout=to,this},init()},ReadCoilsRequest=function(id,start,count){if(!(this instanceof ReadCoilsRequest))return new ReadCoilsRequest(id,start,count);ModbusRequest.call(this,id,12);var body,init=function(){body=new DataView(this.getPacket(),7,5),body.setUint8(BODY_FC,READ_COILS),body.setUint16(BODY_START,start),body.setUint16(BODY_COUNT,count)}.bind(this);this.getStart=function(){return start},this.getCount=function(){return count},this.handleResponse=function(data,offset){var pdu=(new DataView(data,offset,7),new DataView(data,offset+7,2)),fc=pdu.getUint8(0),byte_count=pdu.getUint8(1);if(fc>128)return this.reject({errCode:"serverError"}),2;var i,t,j,mask,dv=new DataView(data,offset+9,byte_count),fc_data=[],c=count;for(i=0;i<count;i+=1)for(t=dv.getUint8(i),j=0;j<7&&(mask=1<<j,fc_data.push(t&0!==mask),c-=1,0!==c);j+=1);return this.resolve(fc_data,this),byte_count+2},init()};ReadCoilsRequest.inherits(ModbusRequest);var ReadHoldingRegistersRequest=function(id,start,count){if(!(this instanceof ReadHoldingRegistersRequest))return new ReadHoldingRegistersRequest(id,start,count);ModbusRequest.call(this,id,12);var body,init=function(){body=new DataView(this.getPacket(),7,5),body.setUint8(BODY_FC,READ_HOLDING_REGISTERS),body.setUint16(BODY_START,start),body.setUint16(BODY_COUNT,count)}.bind(this);this.getStart=function(){return start},this.getCount=function(){return count},this.handleResponse=function(data,offset){var pdu=(new DataView(data,offset,7),new DataView(data,offset+7,2)),fc=pdu.getUint8(0),byte_count=pdu.getUint8(1);if(fc>128)return this.reject({errCode:"serverError"}),2;for(var dv=new DataView(data,offset+7+2,byte_count),fc_data=[],i=0;i<byte_count/2;i+=1)fc_data.push(dv.getUint16(2*i));return this.resolve(fc_data,this),byte_count+2},init()};ReadHoldingRegistersRequest.inherits(ModbusRequest);var ReadInputRegistersRequest=function(id,start,count){if(!(this instanceof ReadInputRegistersRequest))return new ReadInputRegistersRequest(id,start,count);ModbusRequest.call(this,id,12);var body,init=function(){body=new DataView(this.getPacket(),7,5),body.setUint8(BODY_FC,READ_INPUT_REGISTERS),body.setUint16(BODY_START,start),body.setUint16(BODY_COUNT,count)}.bind(this);this.getStart=function(){return start},this.getCount=function(){return count},this.handleResponse=function(data,offset){var pdu=(new DataView(data,offset,7),new DataView(data,offset+7,2)),fc=pdu.getUint8(0),byte_count=pdu.getUint8(1);if(fc>128)return this.reject({errCode:"serverError"}),2;for(var dv=new DataView(data,offset+7+2,byte_count),fc_data=[],i=0;i<byte_count/2;i+=1)fc_data.push(dv.getUint16(2*i));return this.resolve(fc_data,this),byte_count+2},init()};ReadInputRegistersRequest.inherits(ModbusRequest);var WriteSingleCoilRequest=function(id,address,value){if(!(this instanceof WriteSingleCoilRequest))return new WriteSingleCoildRequest(id,address,value);ModbusRequest.call(this,id,12);var body,init=function(){body=new DataView(this.getPacket(),7,5),body.setUint8(BODY_FC,WRITE_SINGLE_COIL),body.setUint16(BODY_START,address),body.setUint16(BODY_COUNT,value?65280:0)}.bind(this);this.getAddress=function(){return address},this.getValue=function(){return value},this.handleResponse=function(data,offset){var pdu=(new DataView(data,offset,7),new DataView(data,offset+7,5)),fc=pdu.getUint8(0);pdu.getUint8(1),pdu.getUint16(3);return fc>128?(this.reject({errCode:"serverError"}),2):(this.resolve(this),5)},init()};WriteSingleCoilRequest.inherits(ModbusRequest);var WriteSingleRegisterRequest=function(id,address,value){if(!(this instanceof WriteSingleRegisterRequest))return new WriteSingleRegisterRequest(id,address,value);ModbusRequest.call(this,id,12);var body,init=function(){body=new DataView(this.getPacket(),7,5),body.setUint8(BODY_FC,WRITE_SINGLE_REGISTER),body.setUint16(BODY_START,address),body.setUint16(BODY_COUNT,value)}.bind(this);this.getAddress=function(){return address},this.getValue=function(){return value},this.handleResponse=function(data,offset){var pdu=(new DataView(data,offset,7),new DataView(data,offset+7,5)),fc=pdu.getUint8(0);pdu.getUint16(1),pdu.getUint16(3);return fc>128?(this.reject({errCode:"serverError"}),2):(this.resolve(this),5)},init()};WriteSingleRegisterRequest.inherits(ModbusRequest);var WriteMultipleRegistersRequest=function(id,address,values){if(!(this instanceof WriteMultipleRegistersRequest))return new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(id,address,values);ModbusRequest.call(this,id,13+2*values.length);var body,init=function(){body=new DataView(this.getPacket(),7,6+2*values.length),body.setUint8(BODY_FC,WRITE_MULTIPLE_REGISTERS),body.setUint16(1,address),body.setUint16(3,values.length),body.setUint8(5,2*values.length),values.forEach(function(v,i){body.setUint16(6+2*i,v)})}.bind(this);this.getAddress=function(){return address},this.getValues=function(){return values},this.handleResponse=function(data,offset){var pdu=(new DataView(data,offset,7),new DataView(data,offset+7,5)),fc=pdu.getUint8(0);pdu.getUint16(1),pdu.getUint16(3);return fc>128?(this.reject({errCode:"serverError"}),2):(this.resolve(this),5)},init()};WriteMultipleRegistersRequest.inherits(ModbusRequest);var ModbusRequestManager=function(){if(!(this instanceof ModbusRequestManager))return new ModbusRequestManager;StateMachine.call(this,"ready");var queue=[],currentRequest=null,socketId=null,receiveBuffer=[],init=function(){chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceive.addListener(receiveListener),this.on("state_changed",function(oldState,newState){"ready"===newState&&send()}.bind(this))}.bind(this),receiveListener=function(info){if(info.socketId===socketId){if(!this.inState("waiting"))throw new Error('ModbusRequestManager - Received Packet while in state "waiting".');receiveBuffer.push(info),handleResponse()}}.bind(this),handleResponse=function(){if(null!==receiveBuffer.length){var response=receiveBuffer.shift(),data=response.data;if(!(data.byteLength<7)){var mbap=new DataView(data,0,7),tid=mbap.getUint16(0);currentRequest&&currentRequest.getId()===tid&&(clearTimeout(currentRequest.getTimeout()),currentRequest.handleResponse(data,0),this.setState("ready"))}}}.bind(this),send=function(){if(0!==queue.length){this.setState("sending"),currentRequest=queue.shift();var timeout_no=setTimeout(function(){currentRequest.reject({errCode:"timeout"}),this.fire("error",[{errCode:"timeout"}])}.bind(this),5e3);currentRequest.setTimeout(timeout_no),chrome.sockets.tcp.send(socketId,currentRequest.getPacket(),function(sendInfo){return sendInfo.resultCode<0?(currentRequest.reject({errCode:"sendError"}),void this.setState("ready")):void this.setState("waiting")}.bind(this))}}.bind(this);this.setSocketId=function(id){return socketId=id,this},this.sendPacket=function(packet){if(queue.push(packet),null===socketId)throw new Error("ModbusRequestManager - No socketId provided.");if(this.inState("ready"))return send(),this},this.clear=function(){for(;queue.length>0;)queue.pop().reject({errCode:"clientOffline"});this.setState("ready")},this.flush=function(){if(null!==socketId)return send(),this},init()};ModbusRequestManager.inherits(StateMachine),ModbusClient=function(timeout,autoreconnect){if(!(this instanceof ModbusClient))return new ModbusClient(timeout,autoreconnect);StateMachine.call(this,"init");var socketId,host="localhost",port=502,id=0,requestManager=new ModbusRequestManager,isReconnecting=!1,init=function(){timeout||(timeout=5e3),requestManager.on("error",function(err){this.inState("offline")||(this.fire("error",[err]),autoreconnect?this.reconnect():this.disconnect())}.bind(this)),this.on("state_changed",function(oldState,newState){this.fire(newState),"error"===oldState&&"online"===newState&&requestManager.flush()}.bind(this)),this.on("offline",function(){requestManager.clear()}.bind(this)),this.on("online",function(){isReconnecting=!1}.bind(this)),this.on("error",function(){isReconnecting=!1}.bind(this)),createSocket()}.bind(this),onReceiveError=function(info){if(info.socketId===socketId)return this.setState("offline"),this.fire("error",[{errCode:"ServerError",args:arguments}]),autoreconnect?void this.reconnect():void this.close()}.bind(this),createSocket=function(){chrome.sockets.tcp.onReceiveError.addListener(onReceiveError),chrome.sockets.tcp.create({},function(createInfo){socketId=createInfo.socketId,requestManager.setSocketId(socketId),this.setState("offline"),this.fire("ready")}.bind(this))}.bind(this),createNewId=function(){return id=(id+1)%1e4}.bind(this),sendPacket=function(req){this.inState("online")&&requestManager.sendPacket(req)}.bind(this);this.isOnline=function(){return this.inState("online")}.bind(this),this.readCoils=function(start,count){var request=new ReadCoilsRequest(createNewId(),start,count);return this.inState("online")?(sendPacket(request),request.getPromise()):(request.reject({errCode:"offline"}),request.getPromise())},this.readHoldingRegisters=function(start,count){var request=new ReadHoldingRegistersRequest(createNewId(),start,count);return this.inState("online")?(sendPacket(request),request.getPromise()):(request.reject({errCode:"offline"}),request.getPromise())},this.readInputRegisters=function(start,count){var request=new ReadInputRegistersRequest(createNewId(),start,count);return this.inState("online")?(sendPacket(request),request.getPromise()):(request.reject({errCode:"offline"}),request.getPromise())},this.writeSingleCoil=function(address,value){var request=new WriteSingleCoilRequest(createNewId(),address,value);return this.inState("online")?(sendPacket(request),request.getPromise()):(request.reject({errCode:"offline"}),request.getPromise())},this.writeSingleRegister=function(address,value){var request=new WriteSingleRegisterRequest(createNewId(),address,value);return this.inState("online")?(sendPacket(request),request.getPromise()):(request.reject({errCode:"offline"}),request.getPromise())},this.writeMultipleRegisters=function(address,values){var request=new WriteMultipleRegistersRequest(createNewId(),address,values);return this.inState("online")?(sendPacket(request),request.getPromise()):(request.reject({errCode:"offline"}),request.getPromise())};var connect=function(){if(!this.inState("connecting")&&!this.inState("online"))return this.setState("connecting"),this.fire("busy"),chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(socketId,host,port,function(result){return 0!==result?(this.fire("error",[{errCode:"connectionError",result:result}]),void(autoreconnect&&this.reconnect(5e3))):void this.setState("online")}.bind(this)),this}.bind(this);this.setHost=function(h){return host=h,this},this.setPort=function(p){return port=p,this},this.getHost=function(){return host},this.getPort=function(){return port},this.connect=function(){return connect(),this},this.disconnect=function(cb){if(!this.inState("disconnecting"))return this.setState("disconnecting"),this.fire("busy"),chrome.sockets.tcp.disconnect(socketId,function(){this.setState("offline"),cb&&cb()}.bind(this)),this},this.close=function(cb){this.disconnect(function(){chrome.sockets.tcp.close(socketId,function(){this.setState("init"),socketId=null,!cb}.bind(this))}.bind(this))};var reconnect=function(){return this.inState("offline")?void connect():void chrome.sockets.tcp.disconnect(socketId,function(){this.setState("offline"),connect()}.bind(this))}.bind(this);this.reconnect=function(wait){isReconnecting||(isReconnecting=!0,this.fire("reconnecting"),setTimeout(function(){reconnect()}.bind(this),wait?wait:0))},init()},ModbusClient.inherits(StateMachine);var RangeList=function(max){if(!(this instanceof RangeList))return new RangeList(max);var list=[],shrink=function(){if(1===list.length)return optimize(),this;for(var next,j=0;j<list.length-1;)cur=list[j],next=list[j+1],cur.end>=next.start-1?(cur.end=Math.max(cur.end,next.end),list.splice(j+1,1)):j+=1;optimize()}.bind(this);this.merge=function(start,end){if(end<=start)return this;if(0===list.length)return list.push({start:start,end:end}),this;for(var i in list){if(cur=list[i],cur.start>end)return list.splice(i,0,{start:start,end:end}),shrink(),this;if(cur.start>=start&&cur.end>start){if(cur.end<end)return cur.start=start,cur.end=start+end,shrink(),this;if(cur.end>=end)return cur.start=start,cur.end=cur.end,shrink(),this}if(cur.start<start&&cur.end>start){if(cur.end>=end)return shrink(),this;if(cur.end<end)return cur.end=end,shrink(),this}}return list.push({start:start,end:end}),shrink(),this};var optimize=function(){if(max)for(var i=0;i<list.length;i+=1)list[i].end-list[i].start>max&&(list.splice(i+1,0,{start:list[i].start+max,end:list[i].end}),list[i].end=list[i].start+max)}.bind(this);this.getList=function(){return list}};"undefined"!=typeof exports&&(exports.RangeList=RangeList),ModbusLoop=function(client,duration){if(!(this instanceof ModbusLoop))return new ModbusLoop(client,duration);StateMachine.call(this,"stop");var startTime,endTime,midTime,readInputRegistersList=new RangeList(125),readHoldingRegistersList=new RangeList(125),inputRegisters=(new RangeList(125),[]),holdingRegisters=[],lastTime=0,init=function(){this.on("state_changed",function(oldState,newState){"start"===newState&&this.fire(newState),"stop"===newState&&this.fire(newState)}.bind(this)),client.on("disconnected",function(){this.setState("stop")}.bind(this)),client.on("error",function(){this.setState("stop")}.bind(this))}.bind(this),updateInputRegisters=function(start,data){for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=1)inputRegisters[start+i]=data[i]}.bind(this),updateHoldingRegisters=function(start,data){for(var i=0;i<data.length;i+=1)holdingRegisters[start+i]=data[i]}.bind(this),executeInputRegistersLoop=function(){var cur,promise,inputsList,retPromise,promisses=[];inputsList=readInputRegistersList.getList();for(var i=0;i<inputsList.length;i+=1)cur=inputsList[i],promise=client.readInputRegisters(cur.start,cur.end-cur.start),promisses.push(promise);return retPromise=$.when.apply(this,promisses).then(function(){var args;args=1===promisses.length?[arguments]:arguments;for(var i=0;i<args.length;i+=1)args[i]&&updateInputRegisters(args[i][1].getStart(),args[i][0])}.bind(this))}.bind(this),executeHoldingRegistersLoop=function(){var cur,promise,inputsList,retPromise,promisses=[];inputsList=readHoldingRegistersList.getList();for(var i=0;i<inputsList.length;i+=1)cur=inputsList[i],promise=client.readHoldingRegisters(cur.start,cur.end-cur.start),promisses.push(promise);return retPromise=$.when.apply(this,promisses).then(function(){var args;args=1===promisses.length?[arguments]:arguments;for(var i=0;i<args.length;i+=1)updateHoldingRegisters(args[i][1].getStart(),args[i][0])}.bind(this))}.bind(this),executeLoop=function(){if(this.inState("running")){startTime=(new Date).getTime();var len_1=readInputRegistersList.getList().length,len_2=readHoldingRegistersList.getList().length,len=len_1+len_2;if(0===len)return void setTimeout(executeLoop.bind(this),1e3);var loop_1=executeInputRegistersLoop(),loop_2=executeHoldingRegistersLoop();$.when.apply(this,[loop_1,loop_2]).then(function(){endTime=(new Date).getTime(),midTime=(lastTime+(endTime-startTime))/2,lastTime=midTime,this.fire("update",[inputRegisters,holdingRegisters,{startTime:startTime,endTime:endTime,midTime:midTime,requestCount:readHoldingRegistersList.getList().length+readInputRegistersList.getList().length,holdingRequests:readHoldingRegistersList.getList(),inputRequests:readInputRegistersList.getList()}]),executeLoop()}.bind(this)).fail(function(){executeLoop()}.bind(this))}}.bind(this);this.readInputRegisters=function(start,count){return readInputRegistersList.merge(start,start+count),this},this.readHoldingRegisters=function(start,count){return readHoldingRegistersList.merge(start,start+count),this},this.start=function(){(this.inState("stop")||this.inState("init"))&&(this.setState("running"),executeLoop())},this.stop=function(){this.setState("stop")},init()},ModbusLoop.inherits(StateMachine);var register_debug_id=0;Register=function(client,loop,start){if(!(this instanceof Register))return new Register(client,loop,start);StateMachine.call(this,"init");var loopListenerId,status=(register_debug_id++,{stateflag_1:!1,stateflag_2:!1,stateflag_3:!1,stateflag_4:!1,state:0,cmd_count:0,cmd_ex:!1,cmd_err:!1,arg:0}),queue=[],cmdId=0;loop.readHoldingRegisters(start,4);var updateStatus=function(inputRegisters,holdingRegisters){var status_reg=holdingRegisters[start],status_arg=holdingRegisters[start+1],s_1=1,s_2=2,s_3=4,s_4=8,s_state=2032,s_cid=14336,s_cide=16384,s_cidf=32768;status.stateflag_1=(status_reg&s_1)>>0,status.stateflag_2=(status_reg&s_2)>>1,status.stateflag_3=(status_reg&s_3)>>2,status.stateflag_4=(status_reg&s_4)>>3,status.state=(status_reg&s_state)>>4,status.cmd_count=(status_reg&s_cid)>>11,status.cmd_ex=(status_reg&s_cide)>>14,status.cmd_err=(status_reg&s_cidf)>>15,status.arg=status_arg,this.inState("init")&&(cmdId=status.cmd_count,this.setState("ready")),this.fire("update_status",[status])}.bind(this),flush=function(){if(0!==queue.length&&this.inState("ready")){this.setState("execution");var first=queue.shift(),command=first.command,defer=first.deferred;cmdId=(cmdId+1)%8;var cmd=command<<3,ex_flag=32768,cmdReg=cmdId+cmd+ex_flag,promisses=[];void 0!==first.param&&promisses.push(client.writeSingleRegister(start+3,first.param)),promisses.push(client.writeSingleRegister(start+2,cmdReg)),$.when.apply(this,promisses).fail(function(err){defer.reject({errCode:"modbusError"}),this.setState("ready")}.bind(this)).then(function(){var handler_id,timeout_id,update_count=0;timeout_id=setTimeout(function(){defer.reject({errCode:"timeout",update_count:update_count}),this.setState("ready")}.bind(this),5e3),handler_id=this.on("update_status",function(status){update_count+=1,status.cmd_count===cmdId&&status.cmd_ex&&(this.off(handler_id),clearTimeout(timeout_id),status.cmd_err?defer.reject({errCode:"plcError"}):defer.resolve(status.arg),this.setState("ready"))}.bind(this))}.bind(this))}}.bind(this);loopListenerId=loop.on("update",updateStatus),this.execute=function(command,param){var defer=$.Deferred();return queue.push({deferred:defer,command:command,param:param}),flush(),defer.promise()},this.on("state_changed",function(oldState,newState){"ready"===newState&&flush()}),this.getStatus=function(){return status},this.getAddress=function(){return start},this.close=function(){return loop.off(loopListenerId),this}},Register.inherits(StateMachine)}()}();


/* end of chrome-modbus*/
(function () {

    var con = document.getElementById('log');

    var log = function (text) {
    
        var e = document.createElement('span'),
            br = document.createElement('br');

        e.innerHTML = text;

        con.appendChild(e);
        con.appendChild(br);
    
    };

    var client  = new ModbusClient(),
        loop    = new Loop(client),
        wr      = 0;

   
    loop.readInputRegisters(10, 4);
    loop.readInputRegisters(14, 4);
    loop.readInputRegisters(18, 4);
    loop.readInputRegisters(30, 4); 

    loop.on('update', function (data) {
    
        console.log(data);

    });

    var write = function () {
    
        var offset  = parseInt($('#offset').val());

        log('Writing ' + wr + ' to ' + offset);

        client.writeSingleRegister(offset, wr++).then(function () {
        
            log('Writing Register done!');

        }).fail(function () {
        
            log('Writing Register failed.');
        
        });
    
    };

    document.getElementById('write').addEventListener('click', write);

    log('Start connection...');

    $('#console').hide();


    client.on('connected', function () {
    
        log('Connection established.');  

        loop.start();

        $('#connect').hide();
        $('#console').show();
  
    });

    client.on('disconnected', function () {
  
        log('Connection closed.');

        loop.stop();

        $('#connect').show();
        $('#disconnect').hide(); 

    });

    client.on('error', function () {

        log('Connection error.');

        loop.stop();

        setTimeout(function () {
        
            client.reconnect();

        }, 5000);

    });

    $('#connect_button').on('click', function () {

        var host    = $('#host').val(),
            port    = parseInt($('#port').val());

        client.connect(host, port);

    });

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>
<html>

    <head>

        <title>jsModbus Chrome App Example 01</title>

    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="connect">

            <label for="host">Host</label>
            <input id="host" type="text" />
            <label for="port">Port</label>
            <input id="port" type="number" />
            <label for="offset">Register Offset</label>
            <input id="offset" type="number" />
            <button id="connect_button">Connect</button>


        </div>

        <div id="console">
            <button id="write">Write Single Register</button>
            <button id="read">Read Input Register</button>
        </div>

        <div id="log"></div>



        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="modbus.min.js"></script>

        <script src="main.js"></script>


    </body>

</html>
```

In my project i'm try to start a comunication between a PLC and a web page, using modbus tcp/ip server from PLC side.
Now I have find this library on the web [chrome-modbus](https://github.com/Cloud-Automation/chrome-modbus) but when I try to use the example 2 the console show me this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'tcp' of undefined
        at new ModbusClient (modbus.min.js:1)
        at main.js:17
        at main.js:103
DevTools failed to load SourceMap: Could not load content for file:///C:/Users/giangiuseppe.serio/Desktop/example_02/jquery.min.map: System error: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
```

The modbus server works because I'have tested it using modscan

Someone can explain me why it doesn't work?

Comment: it's exactly the example 2 but if it is better I insert it

Comment: Hello Giuseppe, have you by any chance clicked the link on your question and read the second paragraph? It reads *...make sure to include jQuery on your App.*

Comment: yes marcos G, I'm using jquery.min.js v2.1.1it's all in the example

Comment: You might wanna go through this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930807/jquery-best-practice-using-document-ready-inside-an-iife. Actually may I know why you're not using document.ready? You might be trying to catch the document elements which isn't available yet by doing so.

Comment: Thanks @ATUL, why that post? I don't use it because I haven't changed the example, and i'm not very able with JS. Can you axplain better?

Comment: Have you tried putting your javascript code inside document.ready? If yes, then do let me know if the error still exists. Actually I'm not able to look into it perfectly as the code snippet of yours if facing issue of js imports.

Comment: It doesn't work the error stilll exists. Now I have modified the code and works in stackoverflow