# $(…).tagsinput is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, plugins

**EDIT**: I can only call `tagsinput()` if I do not use `tagsinput()` in a callback

This is still a problem, because I need to call `tagsinput()` in a callback.

**ORIGINAL**:

I have not been able to find an answer that solves my issue yet:

I am trying to use this library: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

my HTML file includes:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap CDN links -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

```
<select id="el" data-role="tagsinput" name="el" multiple ></select>
```

in script.js (which is connected to multiple HTML files, but the one in question is included above):

```
function addTagToInput() {
  $('#el').tagsinput('add', 'item2');
}
```

After trying to call `addTagToInput()`, I get `$(…).tagsinput is not a function` even though the CDN JS file was properly loaded.

Comment: You didn't include jquery library.

Comment: It is included in my code, but it wasn't in my snippet. My bad, will update my question

Comment: Still, you need to include jquery  before tagsinput.

Comment: Ah, ok - I changed that in my code and updated my snippet. However, after rerunning I get the same error message.

Comment: Wrap your code in document.ready handler. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24930807/jquery-best-practice-using-document-ready-inside-an-iife/24930981#24930981 check out the last code.

Comment: I have the same problem after I put my function inside `$(function(){ });`

Answer (score 0):

The deciding question is still how exactly do you initialize your `tagsinput()`?

Also I think that you get some other errors like network problems or something else, so that the tagsinput or jQuery library will not load. The following code works correctly and I've created a button whose `click` event triggers the `addTagToInput()` function:

```js
$(function() {

  var $el = $('#el'),
    $btnAddTag = $('#add-tag');

  function initInput() {
    $el.tagsinput({
      // add a custom class which run with bootstrap v4
      tagClass: 'badge-dark'
    });
  }

  function addTagToInput() {
    $('#el').tagsinput('add', 'item' + Math.floor(Math.random() * 100));
  }

  initInput();
  addTagToInput();
  $btnAddTag.on('click', addTagToInput);

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.css" />

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-tagsinput/0.8.0/bootstrap-tagsinput.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" id="add-tag">+</button>
<!-- because of adding the initInput() function in jQuery I've deleted the data-role="tagsinput"-->
<select id="el" name="el" multiple ></select>
```

Comment: Thank you for the example. Does this still work if you stick a call to tagsinput() in a callback (i.e. a click listener callback)?

Comment: @StephanieFu Sure, I've edited my answer and add a button whose call the `addTagToInput()` function